# How to use global variable in mysqli_query statement

Tags: mysql, count, global, rows

I'm trying to create a function to count different table rows in my MySQL database. I have the following script, but when executing it, it will generate an error saying that the variable `$con` is not set, but it is. So my question is how can I use "global" in this statement?

```
function countrows($rows){
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $rows");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
echo $num_rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$con` is defined in the global scope (that is, it is not created inside any other functions), then make this call:

```
global $con;
```

as the first line in that function.

You might also pass it as a function parameter:

```
function countrows($rows, $con){
    ...
}
```

Comment: It absolutely should not give an error if it's defined globally... See the PHP page on variable scopes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php Are you certain that you're defining it in the first place?

Comment: ow i got it, simply had to use global $con; before the mysql statement :p thx guys

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it:

```
function countrows($rows){
    global $con;
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $rows");
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    echo $num_rows;
}
```

BTW, if the table is large, I recommend using `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of `SELECT *`.  The latter requires downloading the entire contents of the table in order to count the rows, the former can usually be done efficiently in SQL.